# Match string in double square brackets considering triple brackets

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I have this regex

```
/(?<=\[\[)(?<search>.*?)(?=\]\])/g
```

and want it to match the first `]` if something in my content ends in triple `]`.
The regex should not be greedy on the captured content, because `[[one]] [[two]]` should be captured separately.
`[[` and `]]` can be substituted, even for single characters.

The content:

```
[[item.property1]] [[item.property2]]
[[item.property[0]]] [[item.property[1]]]
```

Should give the matches `item.property1`, `item.property2`, `item.property[0]` and `item.property[1]`, but with the given regex gives `item.property[0` and `item.property[1` for the last items.

[Live demo (regex101)](https://regex101.com/r/hP3SUw/1)

I tried various ways to lookahead or lookbehind, but because the position of the lookahead is zero-length I cannot find a way to look at the last `]`.

Comment: One level deep: `(?<=\[\[)(?<search>[^][]*(?:\[[^][]*])*[^][]*)(?=]])` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/hP3SUw/3))

Comment: Many levels deep: `(?<=\[\[)(?<search>(?:[^][]|(?<aux>\[(?:[^][]++|(?&aux))*]))*)(?=]])` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/hP3SUw/2))

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks for your answer. `[[` and `]]` can be substituted, even for single characters. So I don't 'know' anything about them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer myself `｡･:*˚:✧｡`

The regex needs to be `(?<=\[\[)(?<search>.*?)(?!.\]\])(?=\]\])`, this also works for other open and close characters.

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/Cfgz6N/1)

Comment: Interesting how you do this ❍ ° ○ ₒ ◯ Under the line it checks if there is not another `]` after `]]`. A more efficient solution can be: [...`(?=\]\](?!\]))`](https://regex101.com/r/76v5kO/1)

Comment: Or to even consume any more closing `]` inside the capturing group: [...`.*?\]*`...](https://regex101.com/r/dIMD4H/1)

Comment: Although that is more efficient (in number of steps to get matches) as I said before: I don't 'know' the characters that are closing, I just have to accept `]]`, `]` or `>` or even `-` and cannot process them in my case (which off course is not elaborated on in this question). But thanks for looking into this and giving more solutions)